# Inheriting a view with view controller class: will the new class instantiate the base's UI objects?

Tags: c#, iphone, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a basic View Controller class with a view and some controls connected to outlets in my MonoTouch application, that describes a custom table cell. From this class I inherit all my other custom cells. It is quite comfortable, but I am not sure if the inherited class will be instantiating the base's view and subviews (and thus eating up double memory)?

The base has a UITableViewCell with three UILabels and two buttons. They are connected to outlets, because I needed to put some common functionality in the base class.

The inherited class has the same views added, but I needed to add them manually. They are wired to outlets using the same names as the outlets in the base class.

If the inherited class indeed instantiates the UI elements of the base along with its own, is there a way for me to take fix it and use just the base's UI elements?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer what I understood. Let's see. You have a UIViewController which manages a UITableViewCell. In IB you connect some controls of your cell to the controller.

I do not understand what you mean by adding the same views manually. Why would you do that?

If you inherit from the UIViewController to extend your basic table cell, it will of course contain all the controls of the base.

If you extend your table cell by adding a bunch of other UIViews to the existing ones, the existing ones won't be overwritten.

Think of the views in IB as a "serialized" version of objects. They are real objects. This means if you have a button and a label in IB, upon loading the thing from IB, a "new UIButton()" and a "new UILabel()" will be executed.

If in your inheriting class you don't need the base stuff, don't inherit.

Are you new to object oriented development? Maybe you should first get into the basics of inheritance, polymorphism and object oriented developing in general - or did I completely misunderstand you question?

Comment: Hello, thanks to the answer. I am new to Interface Builder, and I find it a very confusing tool to work with (but then again, I am coming from Visual Studio). The thing that made me ask this question is that in the view controller's .xib.designer.cs file there is no code that instantiates the subviews (buttons, labels, etc.). It seemed that the designer just reads the instantiation instructions from the .xib file. So in short I was not certain that an inherited view controller would also inherit the xib file and have these buttons, labels, etc instantiated.

Comment: Well, same issue here. I've been Visual Studiolized for many many years and then came Xcode and IB - WHAT A MESS! :-) But then I switched to MonoTouch and went productive within hours as all my C# knowledge helps me. As far as IB is concerned: yes, it is a very weird tool. All views (that's what controls are called in UIKit) are lazy loaded. So you create an outlet in IB and you have a property to access it in your dsesigner.cs.xib. It really IS the thing in the XIB file. If yout think the question is answered, please tick it "answered". Thanks.